# Elasticsearch: match_phrase then regexp ("short-circuit") (slow regex)

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to match_phrase then then regexp. The match_phrase happens quick and narrows down the result substantially and thus I would only like to regex on those results. How can I do do this? I have tried a few things, but I'm currently I'm looking at:

```
{
  "query": {
    "constantScore": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "query": {
              "match_phrase": {
                "myfield1": "something something something"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "regexp": {"myfield2": ".*soemthingelsesomethingelse.*"}
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The thing is, I know that the `match_phrase` on its own takes about 10 seconds and will for example, return a single document, but then when I add the regex in and the time hits 30 seconds, and still only returns a single document. Clearly it is not working as I would think it would. Clearly it is regexing on more than a single document. It does not take 20 seconds to regex on a single doc!

myfield2 is not analysed. I require full regexing ability on it as if it were simply text. Hence why it is very important to only regex on it if match_phrase is true.

Thanks!

edit: I believe I am looking to "short-circuit" on the match_phrase

edit2: Another try

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "myfield1": "something something something"
          }
        },
        {
          "regexp": {
            "myfield2": ".*soemthingelsesomethingelse.*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Edit3: This sort of proves that something isn't right, because this is slow

```
{
  "query": {
    "ids": {
      "type": "aaa",
      "values": [
        "AU8wgJipa1wkLOvkEVEL"
      ]
    }
  },
    "post_filter": {
    "regexp": {
      "field2": ".*somethingelse.*"
    }
  }
}
```

This I would have thought would for sure be doing a regex on one document. If this were a grep on the same document in .txt format it would be instant.

Comment: Contrary to the norm, I think I actually need a top level filter here. Usually filters are faster, but since I'm doing random regex, the query is actually much faster.